# Difference between "or" and bitwise operator in Python

Tags: python, operators

I am fairly new to python programming, and recently I ran into this problem.

```
while(True):
panelType = input("Enter the type of panel[a, b, c, d]: ")
if(panelType.lower() != "a"
    | panelType.lower() != "b"
    | panelType.lower() != "c"
    | panelType.lower() != "d"):
    logger.error("Not a valid input. Try Again")
else:
    break
```

When I use bitwise operator I get this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`. However, once I changed it to OR operator, it worked well.

Could anyone explain why this occurred?

Thanks

Comment: Use `if panelType.lower() not in set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!=` has lower precedence than `|` so it tried calculating `"a" | panelType.lower()` which makes no sense.

`|` is an operator meant for numbers, similar to `*` or `+`, so it makes sense you'd calculate it before making comparisons such as `>` or `!=`. You want `or` in this case, which has even lower precedence.

Better yet:

```
if panelType.lower() in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'):
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the help. I tried to find answers in other posts, but I just didn't know what to search